# How to transform a string of maps coordinates into an array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I am drawing trails on a map and the coordinates of the trail are saved as string in a json file in the following format:
(43.886758784865066, 24.226741790771484),(43.90271630763887, 24.234981536865234)

I need to get these values and add them to an array:
coordinates= [43.886758784865066, 24.226741790771484,43.90271630763887, 24.234981536865234];

So how can I do this transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that way

```
var string = '(43.886758784865066, 24.226741790771484),(43.90271630763887, 24.234981536865234)';
string.match(/\d+(\.\d+)/g).map(function(d){return d;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use regular expressions to parse those strings.

```
const match = string.match(/\((.*)\, (.*)\),\((.*)\, (.*)\)/)
/*
  Matches
  ["(43.886758784865066, 24.226741790771484),(43.90271630763887, 24.234981536865234)", "43.886758784865066", "24.226741790771484", "43.90271630763887", "24.234981536865234"]
*/
const Array.prototype.slice.call(match).splice(1, 4)
/* Converts to array and takes the last three elements 
["43.886758784865066", "24.226741790771484", "43.90271630763887", "24.234981536865234"]
*/
```